# GD2 extension on PHP 5.6.14 OS Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and LAMP server. By default the installed version of php had been 5.5, so I had to upgrade to 5.6 according to the manuals on the  [web](http://joshtronic.com/2014/08/31/upgrade-to-php-56-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/) .
After the upgrade the GD extension is not working well.
I tried:
`sudo apt-get remove -purge php5-gd`  -  to remove and purge the installed extension.
`sudo apt-get install php5-gd` - to install again.
Then I test the installation and this is the output:
`sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

> `Reading package lists... Done`
>   `Building dependency tree`
>   `Reading state information... Done`
>   `php5-gd is already the newest version.`

Unfortunately I don't see the GD extension in `phpinfo` page and the test script from the application which I am trying to run also gives me error about GD2.
[image: Error from web app]

I have tried almost every suggestion that I found in Google, but find no joy. You are my last hope now. Thank you.

Comment: Is the load extension line in your php.ini? I am guessing it got installed to the wrong directory. Something similar happened to me once with xdebug.

Comment: gd.so is in the correct dir `/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so`   and there is a **20-gd.ini** file in `conf.d` dir that should load the extension. However I have added a line `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so` manually into php.ini file and no changes.

Comment: `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` or `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d`?

Comment: `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`  
for your info: 
`ls /etc/php5/`
>`apache2  cli  mods-available`

Comment: Just installed Debian 8.2 and made a test. The situation is the same. Something is wrong with the GD extension. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The next thing I would check is the logs to see if there is anything helpful. Did it work with the stock php 5.5, or did that have the same problem?

Comment: It works with stock php 5.5. Which logs should I look in ? I switched to Debian and I have tried to install different versions of php with phpbrew. Unfortunately no joy. I have installed `libgd2-xpm-dev*` and now I can see GD section in `phpinfo`, but the application still say that GD is off.

Comment: By default the log file is `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Ok. I figured out what is going on. The php5-gd is working. I tested with php function `gd_info()`. The problem is that installed version is 2.1.1-**dev**. And I think that this web application is not smart enough to remove dev from them string and then to compare for  compatibility. However, do you know a way to install non **dev** version, or to change it some how in configuration files ? Thank you for the previous advice you were very useful.

Comment: The only time I installed a non default php on an ubuntu LTS I used this PPA https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6 It worked fine with all extensions just using `apt-get` You seem to be using nonstandard repository settings anyway.